# Will my both type C and type D schengen visa be valid if I travel using one of them?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I have both type C and type D schengen visa for the same country as my spouse stays over there. Now, my question is if I visit with type C visa first as my work assignment is not yet confirmed , will the type D visa will become invalid?

P.S : Both the visa's TOT AU UNTIL time period is near about same date .